# dataservice wso2 create generate response

Tags: postgresql, api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I would like to create a dataservice in wso2 with a query with? How to make? the query would be this:

```
with servicos as (
select cast(tec_servico as text) || '-' || ser_nome as servico,
       ser_metodo as metodo,
       coalesce(tec_vl_maximo, 0) as maximo,
       teh_tipo as origem,
       case when teh_dia_semana = 4410 then 0
            when teh_dia_semana = 4404 then 1
            when teh_dia_semana = 4405 then 2
            when teh_dia_semana = 4406 then 3
            when teh_dia_semana = 4407 then 4
            when teh_dia_semana = 4408 then 5
            when teh_dia_semana = 4409 then 6 end as dia,
       teh_hora_inicial_am as hora_inicial_am,
       teh_hora_final_am as hora_final_am,
       teh_hora_inicial_pm as hora_inicial_pm,
       teh_hora_final_pm as hora_final_pm
  from tb_gcc_ted_configuracao
  join tb_gfc_servico on (tec_servico = ser_cod_serial)
  join tb_gcc_ted_horario on (teh_servico = tec_servico)
  join tb_gen_registro on (reg_id_registro = teh_tipo)
 where reg_cod_registro = :origem
   and (tec_vl_maximo is null 
    or tec_vl_maximo > :valorLancamento)
)

select metodo
  from servicos
 where dia = extract(dow from current_date)
   and (current_time between hora_inicial_am and hora_final_am
    or current_time between hora_inicial_pm and hora_final_pm)
 order by metodo 
 limit 1
```

and gives the error below:

SQL query is not applicable to automate the response

how can i do for wso2 to recognize?

Comment: Do you get error when you paste the query in DSS?

Comment: This error happens when I click on generate respnse.